# how to print multiple rows and column selected from table into another activity in SQLite?

Tags: android, sqlite

i have a transactions table which has t_id, email, bank_name, added, sent, received and balance as columns. There are many records with email as activeuser  and added as not null. I want to pass t_id, email, bank_name, added of all such records from the table where email is activeuser and added is not null. i want to pass this data from DatabaseHelper class to the MainActivity. I'm calling a method from MainActivity to do this. I'm stuck and i don't know what to do next.
The DatabaseHelper class code is:

```
public int[] Added(String activeuser){
        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery("select t_id,email,bank_name,added from transactions where email=? and added is not null",new String[]{activeuser});//LINE 1

    }
```

I'm calling this method from MainActivity as following:

```
int Added=db.Added(activeuser);
```

How can i get the above data from DatabaseHelper class to the MainActivity?What should come after LINE 1 in DatabaseHelper class and I'm calling this method from MainActivity as int is that right or it should be array?

Comment: @MikeT can you help me with this

Answer (score 0):

Change the Added method to return a Cursor so :-

```
public Cursor Added(String activeuser){
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
    return db.rawQuery("select t_id,email,bank_name,added from transactions where email=? and added is not null",new String[]{activeuser});//LINE 1
}
```

In the Activity use :-

```
Cursor csr = db.Added(activeuser);
```

Then you can traverse the Cursor like :-

```
while(csr.moveToNext()) {
    int currentid = csr.getLong(csr.getColumnIndex("t_id"));
    String current_email = csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex("email"));
}
csr.close(); //<<<< Assuming you are done with the cursor
```

- The advantage is that the Cursor has all of the extracted data, not just an `int` per row as you would have if you used `int[]`. At best you could return the all the **t_id**'s and then you have to extract the data again based upon **t_id** to get the data from the other columns.

> I'm calling this method from MainActivity as int is that right or it
>   should be array?

As you defined the `Added` method as `public int[]` then it would return an `int[]` so you'd use `int[] Added=db.Added(activeuser);` as opposed to `int Added=db.Added(activeuser);`

### Addition re comment :-

> the code is working but it only returns the last t_id row details.

There could be two likely causes either only a single row is being returned or that you are using `println` after the lopping through traversing the cursor.

If you use the following this will determine which :-

```
    //Cursor csr = db.Added(activeuser);
    Log.d("CURSORINFO","Number of rows extracted is " + String.valueOf(csr.getCount()));
    while (csr.moveToNext()) {
        Log.d("CURSORINFO",
                "Row " + String.valueOf(csr.getPosition() + 1) +
                        " ID :-" + String.valueOf(csr.getLong(csr.getColumnIndex("t_id"))) +
                        " Email :-" + csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex("email")) +
                        " Bank Name :-" + csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex("bank_name"))
        );
    }
    csr.close();
```

- before entering the loop it will output a line to the log saying how many rows are in the cursor.

  - If **1** then you are only extracting a single row which would contradict you saying

    > There are many records with email as activeuser and added as not null.
  - You would have to determine why the query result appears to contradict what you say.
- If greater then 1 it would indicate that you are not using the `println` in the loop.
- whilst looping through/traversing the Cursor for each row an additional line will be output to the log detailing :-

  - The **position** of the row in the Cursor (1 for the first, 2 for the second ...)
  - The **t_id column** (assuming that it is an alias for the rowid i.e. the column was defined as `t_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` or `t_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT`)
  - The **email** column
  - The **bank_name** column
- If you get multiple lines output to the log, then it would be that the `println` was not used within a loop that traverses the Cursor.

Comment: the while loop will come inside mainactivity or databasehelper class?

Comment: there is no return statement in   public Cursor Added(String activeuser){
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
    return db.rawQuery("select t_id,email,bank_name,added from transactions where email=? and added is not null",new String[]{activeuser});//LINE 1
}

Comment: the code is working but it only returns the last t_id row details. i wanted row details for all such t_id. What changes need to be done? After the while{ ..} csr.close(); I'm using print statement to see if it is returning correct values: System.out.println("EMAIL ID IS======>"+email);    @MikeT

Comment: @PranitDarekar there is a return statment i.e. `return db.rawQuery("`, this will return the Cursor that is returned from the rawQuery.

Comment: @PranitDarekar see **Addition** to the Answer.

Comment: after using the additional code I'm getting more than one row displayed in the log, this means that the query is executed properly and table has more than one record. Now i have one doubt that since we have retrieved the data from table, i want to display it in the textview so how to do this? Thanks@MikeT